# Code branching based on types of interfaces that extend

Tags: typescript, interface, extends, typescript2.8

I have some interfaces that extend from a base:

```
enum eItemType { /* … */ }

interface Item {
    someCommonKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
    type: eItemType;
    weight: number;
    // …
}

interface ItemTypeA extends Item {
    someKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
}

interface ItemTypeB extends Item {
    someOtherKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
}

type tItem = Item | ItemTypeA | ItemTypeB
```

And then I have a method that receives an Item, but it could be a (non-keyword) generic `Item` or `ItemTypeA` or `ItemTypeB`, so I created the union type `tItem`. The method does some common things, and then some specific things based on `item.type` (looping through either `someKeyValPairCollection` or `someOtherKeyValPairCollection`. Typescript freaks out, throwing half a dozen assignment errors, ex `Property 'someKeyValPairCollection' is missing in type Item` (no shit).

The method looks roughly like this:

```
processItem(item: tItem): boolean {
    const isValid: boolean = checkValidity(item);
    if (!isValid) return false;

    _.each(someCommonKeyValPairCollection, () => { /* do some common stuff */ });

    // if (typeof item.someKeyValPairCollection !== 'undefined') // tried first, doesn't like
    if (item.type === eItemType.a) processA(item.someKeyValPairCollection);

    return true;
}
```

How is one supposed to handle `if (item.type === eItemType.a) // do some special stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a discriminated union. A union where one property ( `type` in this case) has a specific value for a particular type. You can read more about the topic [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

```
enum eItemType {
    a, b, c
}

interface Item {
    someCommonKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
    type: eItemType;
    weight: number;
    // …
}
interface ItemTypeA extends Item {
    type: eItemType.a
    someKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
}

interface ItemTypeB extends Item {
    type: eItemType.b
    someOtherKeyValPairCollection: eItemType;
}

interface ItemTypeOther extends Item {
    type: Exclude<eItemType, eItemType.a | eItemType.b>
}


type tItem = ItemTypeA | ItemTypeB | ItemTypeOther
function processItem(item: tItem): boolean {
    if (item.type === eItemType.a) {
        item.someKeyValPairCollection
    }
    else if (item.type === eItemType.b) {
        item.someOtherKeyValPairCollection
    } else {
        item  // will be ItemTypeOther
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit**

Added a simple alternative to have a catch the rest of the enum values without having to define a separate type for each enum value or having to list them individually.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Note that removing `Item` from the union in `tItem` was also necessary. But what happens when it's a basic item? Would I need to create another interface that extends the base (with no extra properties) and add that to the union type? Would I need to do that for every other option in `eItemType` (or, alternatively, explicitly set `ItemTypeBase.type` to a union of all other types)?

Comment: @jacob The `Item` needs to be removed because it has a `type` that can be any value of the enum so the test `item.type === eItemType.a` will only exclude `ItemTypeB`, `item` could still be `ItemTypeA` or `Item` and you will not be able to access `ItemTypeA` properties. You could have a `ItemNonSpecific` with an associated enum entry `eItemType.any`

Comment: Sorry, when you say "The Item needs to be removed", do you mean it needed to be removed from the `tItem` union (because it created ambiguity), or that it should not be directly used (sort of like an abstract class) and only extended, or both?

Comment: Removed from `tItem` for sure, as it creates the ambiguity. You can use it directly but you will not be able to assign it to a `tItem`. For example this is invlaid: `let x!:Item;
let f: tItem = x;`. I would recommend you not use it and have dedicated types for each item in the enum. BTW: you can declare a single type for multiple enum entries using unions of enum literal types : `type: eItemType.a |  eItemType.c`

Comment: I would rather not create an empty interface for every entry in the enum (quite verbose and not future-proof). Is it possible to do something like `type: !(eItem.a | eItem.b)`? Ex I would rename `Item` to something like `ItemAbstract`, have the existing two others extend that instead, and then create a new `Item` with just `type: !A or B` (which every non-A and non-B would implement).

Comment: @jacob added an option to do this using conditional types in ts 2.8. Hope It helps !